# Filter result based on IS AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, filter

I have data from the JSON file. I am showing list of categories but I want to filter the list and show only category with 'parent:0'.

```
"categories": [
            {
                "id": 51,
                "slug": "knarr",
                "title": "Knarr",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 8,
                "post_count": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "slug": "service-vessels",
                "title": "Service Vessels",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 0,
                "post_count": 1
            }
        ],
```

Please check my code here "http://plnkr.co/edit/1vcIAPSwvxQcbIzMhyzp?p=preview"

Comment: Did you research this at all? Angular's `filter` can filter by property values pretty easily

Comment: @Ian, unfortunately something like `filter:{ parent:0 }` will not work, due to filter converting it to a String.

Which means, as soon as you have a property like this:
`"parent": 10`
you gonna have a bad time.

Otherwise I would wholeheartedly agree with you :)

Comment: @flakyfilibuster I'm not sure what you mean, it seems to work fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/NON8p7lSnnZqqBgoBHNi?p=preview and http://jsfiddle.net/dY8xa/

Comment: @Ian - don't be fooled :)

Add this to the ng-repeat:
`<li>{{category.parent}}</li>`

.Filtering by property works, however it filters by string, not by number - I'm no Angular pro, so there might be a way to get around this. If so, this would of course be the most elegant solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: @flakyfilibuster Ooooooh, I see what you're saying. I added what you said to jsFiddle and it worked fine, so I was confused. Then I added it to the plunker and some "10"s showed up. I could've sworn it did an exact match, not a partial match (even if it compares strings, because that shouldn't matter) - I think the problem is the partial matching it does. But good point!

Comment: @flakyfilibuster I actually remember our team encountering something like this recently, because one string contained the other so it was matching both. It seems that you can pass `true` at the end of the expression (`filter:{parent: 0}:true`) and it matches exact: http://plnkr.co/edit/LRDBhBsUiacfC0FOLZ0B?p=preview - it's the `comparator` param here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.3/docs/api/ng.filter:filter

Comment: @Ian Oh wow, that's pretty sweet :) 
Thanks for the find!

I would recommend adding it as an answer to this question - correct answer with one line ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's `filter` provider already has the ability to filter a list (like in `ng-repeat`) by property. In the HTML, this would be like the following:

```
<ul ng-repeat="category in categories | filter:{parent: 0}">
------------------------------ HERE --^
```

**DEMO:** http://plnkr.co/edit/HXvkmar7I7HpgPbv6LVM?p=preview

Unfortunately, the default matching used is partial. That means, if the `parent` property **contains** "0". So for example, any of the items that have `parent: 10` would match as well, as the plunker shows (string comparisons are done on the property values).

Luckily, you can provide `true` in the filter expression and it will do an exact match. That means using this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="category in categories | filter:{parent: 0}:true">
-------------------------------------------------- HERE --^
```

**DEMO:** http://plnkr.co/edit/m22ML9XPf2FnZweuModU?p=preview

---

Also, just as a suggestion, it seems weird to put an `ng-repeat` on a `<ul>` element - I would expect it to be on the `<li>` element.

---

Looking at the comments in the other answers, you were also looking to only display unique categories. Since your JSON implies that categories have unique `id`s, you can create a custom filter for your app like this:

```
app.filter("uniqueCategoryFilter", function () {
  return function (categories) {
    var uniqueCategories, catIds;
    uniqueCategories = [];
    catIds = {};
    if (categories) {
      angular.forEach(categories, function (category) {
        if (!catIds[category.id]) {
          catIds[category.id] = true;
          uniqueCategories.push(category);
        }
      });
    }
    return uniqueCategories;
  };
});
```

And use it like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="category in categories | filter:{parent: 0}:true | uniqueCategoryFilter">
-------------------------------------------------------- HERE --^
```

**DEMO:** http://plnkr.co/edit/3NHuTvQiVHQTZxtIkEGB?p=preview

Make sure this unique filter comes **after** the `parent` property filter.

---

**References:**

- AngularJS API `filter`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own filter in angular, you can try something like this:

```
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
      <ul ng-repeat="category in categories | customFilter:category">
          <li>{{category.title}}</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

and the filter:

```
app.filter('customFilter', [function () {
    return function (items) {
        var filtered = [];

        angular.forEach(items, function (item) {

          if(item.parent === 0 && indexOf(item) < 0) {
            filtered.push(item);
          }
        })

        return filtered;
    }
}]);
```

See the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/96aX0cqLT9SJX2YZquns?p=preview

For more information about filters checkout the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Comment: Any idea of how to make it unique? right now it is displaying "Investors, Gas, Gas" can i make it to display "Investors, Gas"?

Comment: Yeah ofcourse, just modify the filter and check for double values.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter wanted categories:

```
$scope.categories = $scope.categories.filter(function(category) {
  return category.parent === 0;
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/hHe2AS2gzm35mEqnHoQ3?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any idea of how to make it unique? right now it is displaying "Investors, Gas, Gas" can i make it to display "Investors, Gas"?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/hHe2AS2gzm35mEqnHoQ3?p=preview but it will be hard to maintenance in the future